# Remove label from the clone?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the slot has been cloned, the `label` are hidden. Only first slot at the top have a `label` (not hidden).

Currently it is hiding all the labels, how to solve this?

```
$('.slot-container').on("click", ".btn-add-slot", function(event) {
    var slot = $(this).closest('.slot');
    copySlot = slot;

    $('label', copySlot).hide(); // hide Clone Label

    $(slot).clone().appendTo(".slot-container");

    //hide button from this slot
    $(this).hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slot-container">
    <div class="slot">
        <label>Time</label>
        <input type='text' class='address_field' />
        <button class="btn-add-slot">
          Add Slot +
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/7966/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you need to call `hide()` on the `label` element within the cloned element only. Also note that you can tidy the logic slightly. Try this:

```
$('.slot-container').on("click", ".btn-add-slot", function(event) {
    var $clone = $(this).closest('.slot').clone().appendTo(".slot-container");        
    $clone.find('label').hide();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/7967/)

Answer (score 0):

How about just hide it with CSS?

```css
.slot:not(:first-child) label { visibility: hidden }
```

```html
<div class="slot-container">

  <div class="slot">
    <label>Time</label>
    <input type='text' class='address_field' />
    <button class="btn-add-slot">
      Add Slot +
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="slot">
    <label>Time</label>
    <input type='text' class='address_field' />
    <button class="btn-add-slot">
      Add Slot +
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Or if you're not up for that, the problem with your original code is that you don't actually copy the slot when you assign into `slotCopy`, you just assign it to the same slot.

```
var copySlot = $(slot).clone(); // clone here 
$('label', copySlot).hide(); // hide Clone Label
copySlot.appendTo(".slot-container"); // append now
```

[Here's the updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/7970/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slot-container').on("click", ".btn-add-slot", function(event) {
    var _clone = $(this).closest('.slot').clone(); // clone slot
    $(_clone).find('label').hide(); // hide lablel from cloned element
    _clone.appendTo(".slot-container"); // append cloned slot
    $(this).hide(); //hide button from this slot
  });
});
```

```css
body { padding: 5px; }
label { font-weight: bold; }
input[type=text] { width: 20em; }
p { margin: 1em 0 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slot-container">
  <div class="slot">
    <label>Time</label>
    <input type='text' class='address_field' />
    <button class="btn-add-slot">
      Add Slot +
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just remove in clone object label and button and this is it. If you have questions , just write. Regards

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var slotContainer = '.slot-container';
  
  $(slotContainer).on("click", ".btn-add-slot", function(event) {
    var slot = $(this).closest('.slot');
    copySlot = slot.clone();
    copySlot.find('label, button').remove();
    
    copySlot.prependTo(slotContainer);
   
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 20em
}

p {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slot-container">

  <div class="slot">
    <label>Time</label>
    <input type='text' class='address_field' />
    <button class="btn-add-slot">
      Add Slot +
    </button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```